# Node js render multiple Static Methods

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently learning Node.js to build a website.
I have followed some tuto on youtube about expressjs and I'm able to deal with router and pages that gather information from a mysql DB. I have separed my DB query on a Class file.
I'm able to render information on a html page but I'm a bit stuck when I want to render 2 method of a class.

Here is y code :

ClassSettings.js

```
let connection = require('../config/db')

class Settings {

static platform(cb) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM platforms', (err, rows) => {
        if(err) throw err
        cb(rows)
    })
}

static entities(cb) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM entitymanagement', (err, rows) => {
        if(err) throw err
        cb(rows)
    })
}

}

module.exports = Settings
```

Here is the router part. I can gather information from one method :

```
router.get('/page1', (request, response) => {
  if (request.session.loggedin) {
    ssn=request.session;
    let Settings = require('./models/ClassSettings')
    Settings.platform(function(d){
      response.render('modules/page1', {
          Datas: d,
          session : ssn,
          url : request.originalUrl
      })
    })
  } else {
    response.redirect('/login');
    response.end();
    }
})
```

But how can I "render" both ?

- Settings.platform
- Settings.entities

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node.js, mysql library is working asynchronously, thus you have to pass callbacks to it.

You can use `mysql-promise` and `async/await` or you can call entities method inside platform method's callback.

```
Settings.platform(function (d) {
    Settings.entities(function (e) {
        // entities as e will be available here, so you can pass it to Datas property
        response.render('modules/page1', {
            Datas: d,
            session : ssn,
            url : request.originalUrl
        })
    })
})
```